# SSIS Lookup transformation Ignore Failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, lookup

In the dropdown 'Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries' I see 4 options to choose from:

- Ignore failure
- Redirect rows to error output
- Fail component
- Redirect rows to no match output

In the [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/transformation-custom-properties?view=sql-server-ver16#lookup) I see only two options:

- Treat rows with no matching entries as errors (0)
- Send rows with no matching entries to the no match output (1)

This code accepts only 0 and 1:

```
lookupWrapper.SetComponentProperty("NoMatchBehavior", 1);
```

When I set the property to Ignore Failures, in the XML I see this

```
<property
  dataType="System.Int32"
  description="Specifies ..."
  name="NoMatchBehavior"
  typeConverter="LookupNoMatchBehavior">1</property>
<property
```

How to set a Lookup transformation to ignore failures in the API?

**Update**:

I compared all the differences in the resulting XML when I selected different options. There are two places that differ, in the lookup's NoMatchBehavior property and in the "Lookup Match Output" property errorRowDisposition.

```
                     errorRowDisposition  NoMatchBehavior
Fail Component       "FailComponent"      0
Ignore Failure       "IgnoreFailure"      0
Redirect To No Match  -                   1
Redirect To Error    "RedirectRow"        0
```

After this, sorting out the code is easy.

```
...
lookupWrapper.SetComponentProperty("NoMatchBehavior", 0);
...
lookupMatchOutput.ErrorRowDisposition = DTSRowDisposition.RD_IgnoreFailure;
...
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but create a package with two data flows. One with lookup to ignore failure and one with redirect rows to no match output, and then have an empty derived column as the destination(s). My guess is that it's the "same" under the covers and the real difference is whether the output path is the "default" or a named "no match output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a Lookup transformation to ignore failures in the API we need two things.

1. set it to treat rows with no matching entries as errors
2. ignore these errors in the output

```
...
lookupWrapper.SetComponentProperty("NoMatchBehavior", 0);
...
lookupMatchOutput.ErrorRowDisposition = DTSRowDisposition.RD_IgnoreFailure;
...
```